# Cannot seem to update string var of the number of contents on a txt file

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, var

I made a fairly simple To - Do task manager or task list, I put on a Tkinter Label on the bottom right corner that displays the number of tasks in the data file (the .txt where the tasks are stored) But I can't seem to get it to update after the number changes either by adding a task or deleting one. I'm trying to make the StringVar work, though there might be another solution. I'm pretty new to python, I hope I managed to explain myself.

I've tried converting the "with open data.txt" into a function and then calling it so it gets updated but that gave me multiple errors as I apparently can't set a StringVar that's outside a function from within a function, or at least I couldn't do it. I also thought of counting the items in the Textbox instead of the text file, but sadly I still couldn't make it update after the first time it works (after I open the program).
As I said before, I'm very new to programming so I apologize if my code isn't very understandable, I tried to keep things orderly. I thought a simple while True: would solve it but I had forgotten that wouldn't be possible in Tkinter. I have a theory maybe using threads could fix it but I don't think that would a very efficient fix.

I'm sorry to show most of my code but I'm not entirely sure on what could  be relevant or not

```
root = Tk()

# List
Lista = []


# Defines



def update_list():
    clear_list()
    for task in Lista:
        Box.insert("end", task)

def clear_list():
    Box.delete(0,"end")

def window(sike):
    sike.title('To Do')
    sike.geometry("450x450+750+200")


def del_task():
    task = Box.get(ACTIVE)
    if task in Lista:
        Lista.remove(task)
    update_list()
    with open ("data.txt", "w") as data:
        data.writelines(Lista)


def add_task():
    task = Entry1.get()
    if task !="":
        with open ("data.txt", "a") as data:
            data.write(task)
            data.write('\n')
        Lista.append(task)
        Entry1.delete(0, "end")
        update_list()

# numbers variable (here's the issue)

with open("data.txt", "r") as data:
    numero = data.readlines()
    numberof = len(numero)

var = StringVar()
var.set(numberof)


# Inside the window
window(root)


Title = Label(root, text='My To-Do List', font = "default 10 bold")
Title.place(x=173, y=20)

Quote = Label(root, text='"You can’t build a reputation based on what you are going to do"', font="default 10 italic")
Quote.place(x=35, y=55)


By = Label(root, text='-Henry Ford', font = "default 10 italic")
By.place(x=180, y=85)

AddTask = ttk.Button(root, text='Add Task')
AddTask.place(x=70, y=150)
AddTask.config(command=add_task)

DeleteTask = ttk.Button(root, text='Delete Task')
DeleteTask.place(x=70, y=300)
DeleteTask.config(command=del_task)

Entry1 = Entry(root, width=35)
Entry1.place(x=200, y=150)

Box = Listbox(root, width=35, height=10)
Box.place(x=200, y=240)


numberoftasks = Label(root, textvariable=var)
numberoftasks.place(x=420, y=420)

# Importing from list save
with open ("data.txt") as data:
    line = data.readlines()
    for thing in line:
        Lista.append(thing)
        update_list()


# Just the loop
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You need to update the variable *every time* the length of the list changes. Add this line of code to update_list(): `var.set(len(Lista))`

Comment: Such a simple solution, wow, I worked on it for more than 3 hours last night, thank you! It worked instantly :) do you have any feedback on how I could structure or make my code better? I'm trying these kinds of things as practice

Comment: I would suggest you read and start following the [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) especially regarding [Naming Conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions).